# Insert rows into tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Simply, I am looking for a way to insert zero value rows at specific locations into one tensor. That is, given a tensor `A` for example, and list of `rows=[1, 3]`, I would like to get the following tensor `B`:

```
    | ? ? ? |       | ? 0 ? 0 ? |
A = | ? ? ? |   B = | ? 0 ? 0 ? |
    | ? ? ? |       | ? 0 ? 0 ? |
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved using `tf.stack`:

```
# Input
a = tf.constant(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), tf.float32)
#[[0. 1. 2.]
# [3. 4. 5.]
# [6. 7. 8.]]

b = tf.zeros_like(a)
c = tf.reshape(tf.stack([a,b], 2),
               [-1, tf.shape(a)[1]+tf.shape(b)[1]])[:,:-1]

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(c))
#[[0. 0. 1. 0. 2.]
# [3. 0. 4. 0. 5.]
# [6. 0. 7. 0. 8.]]
```

Comment: I realized that I posted a wrong example. `A` had 4 columns and after insertion it had 5. Corrected it now, and tested your code. It doesn't seem to work for the example provide, indices go out of range.